# using loops and methods together

Tags: c#, loops, methods

Recently i made a simple calculator to test myself but it was clunky and cluttered because it used a large number of if statements so i used switches to clean it up. recently i learned how to use methods and tried to move each part of the code into a separate and relevant methods. But, some of my code uses loops to return to the start of the code to act as a reset function and now it doesn't work because it doesn't recognize that it is a part of a loop. i tried calling all the methods in a loop inside the main method but it still didn't work. how can i fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Class1
    {
        static int num1 = 0;
        static int num2 = 0;
        static int answer = 0;
        static string sumType = " ";
        static string consoleContinue = " ";
        static void GetUserInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter your first value");
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("please enter your second value");
            num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        static void GetSumType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("would you like to add, subtract, multiply or divide?");
            Console.WriteLine("alternitavely type quit to exit the program");
            sumType = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (sumType.ToLower())
            {
                case "add":
                    answer = (num1 + num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "subtract":
                    answer = (num1 - num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "multiply":
                    answer = (num1 * num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "divide":
                    answer = (num1 / num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "quit":
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void ConsoleContnue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("do you wish to continue? type yes to continue and no to exit the program");
            consoleContinue = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (consoleContinue.ToLower())
            {
                case "yes":
                    continue;
                    break;
                case "no":
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                GetUserInput();
                GetSumType();
                ConsoleContnue();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify on what isn't working exactly?

Comment: case "yes":
                    continue

Comment: that part returns an error because it doesn't recognize that the method is called later in a loop which would make the continue; loop function work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "ConsoleContnue()" function -> in the switch statement for "yes" you can remove the "continue" so it looks like this:

```
 switch (consoleContinue.ToLower())
        {
            case "yes":
                break;
            case "no":
                Environment.Exit(-1);
                break;
        }
```

Then your code seems to run perfectly.

However, I would change it to a simple one liner since you only care about the "no" clause:

```
if (consoleContinue.ToLower() == "no") Environment.Exit(-1);
```